# Set site collection readonly remotely in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, wss-3.0

I have a requirement to set a site collection in read only mode in SharePoint 2007 remotely (not from the SharePoint servers).

As far as I know there is no web service available to do this. One way I figured out was to set the content database itself read only and it sets all site collections in that database read only. And, I'm not sure if this is supported.

Could someone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box web service in SharePoint 2007 that does what you want. However if you have access to Central Admin, there are options in there to set a site to Read Only.